# How to define an image as a display-table entry

Tags: buffer-display-table

Is there any way to create a custom image (e.g., using an xpm format) and use it in the `display-table`?

I see that XEmacs had a function called `make-glyph` -- e.g., `(make-glyph '([xpm :file "~/something.xpm"] [string :data "[END]"]))`.  However, regular Emacs doesn't have that function.

The function `make-glyph-code` requires a *character* (e.g., `?\U0001D4D5`) -- and there is an optional `face` argument (e.g., `'font-lock-warning-face`).

I would like to do something similar to:

```
(when (not buffer-display-table)
  (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table)))

(aset buffer-display-table ?\014 form-feed)

(defvar form-feed `(image :type xpm :mask nil :ascent center :data
  "/* XPM */
  static char * form_feed_xpm[] = {
  \"11 20 5 1\",
  \" c None\",
  \". c purple\",
  \"+ c yellow\",
  \"@ c #7F0000\",
  \"% c yellow\",
  \"%%%%%%%%%%%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%...++++++%\",
  \"%.++.++...%\",
  \"%+...+....%\",
  \"%+...+....%\",
  \"%+...+....%\",
  \"%+...++++.%\",
  \"%....+....%\",
  \"%...++....%\",
  \"%...+.....%\",
  \"%.++++....%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%.........%\",
  \"%%%%%%%%%%%\"};"))
```

---

**EDIT**:  As a first impression, it seemed that the library `gamegrid.el` might have been using the concept outlined above.  However, it turned out that `gamegrid.el` uses the `buffer-display-table` as a buffer-local storage facility for the `xpm` images, which are later used by the function `gamegrid-set-face` to `add-text-properties` using the `'display` property.  While it was a good excuse to play *pong* and *tetris*, it did not resolve this particular question.